# Boost test does not init_unit_test_suite

Tags: c++, testing, boost, boost-test

I run this piece of code

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/test/unit_test_log.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::unit_test;
using namespace std;


void TestFoo()
{
    BOOST_CHECK(0==0);
}

test_suite* init_unit_test_suite( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::cout << "Enter init_unit_test_suite" << endl;
    boost::unit_test::test_suite* master_test_suite = 
                        BOOST_TEST_SUITE( "MasterTestSuite" );
    master_test_suite->add(BOOST_TEST_CASE(&TestFoo));
    return master_test_suite;

}
```

But at runtime it says

> > Test setup error: test tree is empty

Why does it not run the init_unit_test_suite function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you actually dynamically link against the boost_unit_test framework library? Furthermore, the combination of manual test registration and the definition of `BOOST_TEST_MAIN` does not work. The dynamic library requires slightly different initialization routines.

The easiest way to avoid this hurdle is to use [automatic test registration](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-organization/auto-test-suite.html)

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/test/unit_test_log.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::unit_test;
using namespace std;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(MasterSuite)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(TestFoo)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(0==0);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

This is more robust and scales much better when you add more and more tests.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "the combination of manual test registration and the definition of BOOST_TEST_MAIN does not work". I have the same problem, but would like to use manual test registration. Is this possible?

Comment: @user867377 I don't know, I avoid manual registration as the plague because it is very tedious. You could ask a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725874/boost-unittest-framework-with-dynamic-linking-and-manual-setup

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same issue. Besides switching to [automatic test registration](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-organization/auto-test-suite.html), as suggested [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17024709/172695), you can also use static linking, i.e. by replacing

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
```

with

```
#define BOOST_TEST_STATIC_LINK
```

This was suggested at the [boost mailing list](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Test-tree-is-empty-td2580070.html):

> The easiest way to fix this is to [...] link with static library.
>
> Dynamic library init API is slightly different since 1.34.1 and this is the
> cause of the error you see. init_unit_test_suite function is not called in this
> case.