# Boost unittest framework with dynamic linking and manual setup

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I am trying to setup a boost unittest framework with dynamic linking and manual setup (Not BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE). I have made a trivial example to reproduce my errors:

```
//SomeLib.cpp
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include "SomeLib.h"
int getImportantNumber(){return 1729;}
int increaseNumber(int number){return number+1;}

//SomeTests.cpp
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include "lib/SomeLib.h"
#include "SomeTests.h"
using namespace boost::unit_test;

void SomeTests::numberIs1729(){
    BOOST_CHECK(getImportantNumber() == 1729);
}
void SomeTests::increase(){
    BOOST_CHECK(increaseNumber(1) == 2);
}

//ChainedInc.cpp
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include "lib/SomeLib.h"
#include "ChainedInc.h"
using namespace boost::unit_test;

void ChainedInc::incinc(){
    BOOST_CHECK(increaseNumber(increaseNumber(1)) == 3);
}
void ChainedInc::incincinc(){
    BOOST_CHECK(increaseNumber(increaseNumber(increaseNumber(1))) == 4);
}

//Master.cpp
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include "SomeTests.h"

using namespace boost::unit_test;
test_suite* init_unit_test_suite( int, char** )
{
    test_suite* ts1 = BOOST_TEST_SUITE( "Suite1" );

    boost::shared_ptr<SomeTests> test1 ( new SomeTests());
    ts1->add( BOOST_TEST_CASE( boost::bind(&SomeTests::numberIs1729, test1)));
    ts1->add( BOOST_TEST_CASE( boost::bind(&SomeTests::increase, test1)));

    framework::master_test_suite().add( ts1 );
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/g++ test/ChainedInc.cpp.1.o test/Master.cpp.1.o test/SomeTests.cpp.1.o lib/SomeLib.cpp.2.o -o /home/mto/src/manualBoost/build/test/app -Wl-Bdynamic -L/usr/lib64 -lboost_unit_test_framework

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is usally solved by adding

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
```

to all test files and

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE something
```

to exactly one arbitrary test file. However the last define does not work well when the boost tests are registered manually. If I try to run my tests after using this define I get

```
build/test/app

Test setup error: test tree is empty
```

See [Boost test does not init_unit_test_suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024143/boost-test-does-not-init-unit-test-suite). Is it possible to use boost manual registration and dynamic linking against boost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get Manual setup of test to work with dynamic linking to boost when I used the header only libraries.

```
-#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
+#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
```

Answer (score 3):

BOOST_TEST_MAIN should only ever be defined in one module.  It pulls in a definition of main.  If you define it in multiple modules, then you'll have multiply defined main.

See my [documentation rewrite](http://user.xmission.com/~legalize/boost.test/libs/test/doc/html/index.html) for explanation of these configuration macros.

Comment: thanks much for the Boost docs rewrite - much easier to read and understand. Big help!

Answer (score 1):

The required define is `#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN` as per your linked question.

Your code as presented does not contain this define (nor `BOOST_TEST_MODULE`)

As I understand [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/compilation.html#utf.flag.main), you need `BOOST_TEST_MAIN` when you define `init_unit_test_suite` yourself and you use `BOOST_TEST_MODULE` if you use the automatic stuff:

> `BOOST_TEST_MODULE`-- Define this flag to *generate the test module
>   initialization function*, which uses the defined value to name the
>   master test suite. In case of dynamic library variant default function
>   main() implementation is generated as well

---

Also, an [old example from the boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/test/doc/components/utf/index.html) shows this:

```
test_suite*
init_unit_test_suite( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    test_suite* test = BOOST_TEST_SUITE( "Master test suite" );

    test->add( BOOST_TEST_CASE( &my_test_function ) );

    return test;  //++++++++++++++
}
```

which is what we do for master test suite setup (we're on Boost 1.44 atm.)

But your code above shows this:

```
    ...
    framework::master_test_suite().add( ts1 );
    return 0;
}
```

which seems to be from some newer part of the Boost.Test docs.

Maybe you need to return the master test suite (once) in the `init_unit_test_suite` function? Have you tried this?

Comment: Either BOOST_TEST_MODULE or BOOST_TEST_MAIN in combination with BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK result in the error above. "Test setup error: test tree is empty"

Comment: I have not tried this. Since we managed to get it working with the solution i proposed it is not so urgent, but I will test it if I get time